# confused with jpanel behaviour

Tags: java, swing

i created a java swing frame and it contain a panel named anim.i use netbean ide for that.i have set it's width to 100 .i want to change it's width to 500 by clicking a jbutton.when i click it's width changed to 500 as i expect.but when i focus anywhere of my jframe ,my jpanel width changed to it's initial size 100.this is my code.i want to know how can i change it's width to 500 without change to it's initial size.

```
 anim.setSize(500, 400);
```

this image shows my problem

[image]

Comment: when are you stopping the timer? If you are not doing this then it will never stop repeating the task. there is no need to use a flag simply stop the timer `timer.stop()` instead of using `a=false;` For fast response please share minimal testable code.

Comment: Your code does _not_ compile. Read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're asking for help, yet you're not 1. follow the link and 2. Create a simple example we can run _without_ having to create an application ourselves, which may or may not replicate your problem.

Comment: This question is utterly unclear to me. Clearly state your problems. And please reformat your code ;-)

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha: Please have a look at this [PanelWithTimer.java link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cg6wcoxd5bn16td/PanelWithTimer.java). See if this helps in solving the problem faced by you :-)

Comment: of couse it's working.and that's what i looking for.tnx you.i have to figureout why mine code not work